# REGEX 2 Capture groups to 1 match

Tags: regex

I have a string as follows:

```
"// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

main  = {
data1 = value
data2 = value
model_types = [
// Type 1,2,3
{
device_model = ['type1_v1', 'type1_v2']
current_version = '1.2.34.56'
},
{
device_model = ['type2_v1', 'type2_v2']
data3 = value
current_version = 'type2911-54.32'
},
{
device_model = ['type_v3']  // misc data
current_version = '1.2.3-t35_098'
},

// Type 4 and 5
{
device_model = ['type4_v1', 'type4_v2']
data4 = value
data5 = value
current_version = '6.6.9-TY4_998'
},
{
device_model = ['type5_v1', 'type5_v2', 'type5_v3']
data6 = value
current_version = '1.5.6-TY5_354'
data7 = value
},

// Type 6 and Wifi1
{
device_model = ['type6_v1']
current_version = '1.4.65-20240220'
},
{
device_model = ['type6_w1']
current_version = '1.2.3'
},

// Type 7 and Wifi2
{
device_model = ['type7_v1']
data8 = value
current_version = '2.3.6-9'
children = [{
data9 = ['value']
current_version = '4.8.1'
}]
},
{
device_model = ['type7_w2']
data10 = value
current_version = '5.1.4-b'
children = [{
data9 = ['value']
current_version = '8.4.1'
}]
},

// Type 8
{
device_model = ['type8_v1']
current_version = 'ty8-87.41'
data11 = value
},
{
device_model = ['type8_v2']
current_version = 'ty8-87.41'
},

// Type 9
{
device_model = ['type9_v1]
current_version = 'ty9-14.9-v198'
},

// Type 10
{
device_model = ['type10_v1', 'type10_v2']
current_version = '2.2.3.110ty'
},
]
}
"
```

A few weeks ago a kind person was able to provide me a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RH5IUz/1) with a mock up of a similar script I jotted down from memory which I had saved. My actual string is much more simple than I had originally thought and I am attempting to learn/mirror the REGEX from the demo. I have two
separate expressions, 1 for device model and 1 for current version and I would like to consolidate them into one expression, if possible, as shown in the demo. Based on the demo, it looks like it is, but I haven't been able to do so.
Device Model Expression:

```
(?:device_model = \['?|data9 = \['|, ')([^'\],\r\n]*)(?=.*\r?\n(?:[ \t]*\[.*\r?\n)*?[ \t]*)
```

Current Version:

```
"(?:current_version = ')([^'\],\r\n]*)(?=.*\r?\n(?:[ \t]*\[.*\r?\n)*?[ \t]*)
```

Both of which work in Regex101 independently. If I were to mirror the demo the expression would/should look like this.

Desired one line expression:

```
(?:device_model = \['?|data9 = \['|, ')([^'\],\r\n]*)(?=.*\r?\n(?:[ \t]*\[.*\r?\n)*?[ \t]*\[(?::current_version = ')(.*))
```

But this returns an error "Your regular expression does not match the subject string." To me, it looks like the demo just appended a second non-capture group ("current software" variants) and had it return 2 groups for every 1 match. EG: https://imgur.com/a/YWydFTy

Can anyone pinpoint what needs to be changed in the desired one line expression so that I can get the same output as the demo?

Comment: Is this the same as your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78043504/regex-to-extract-2-data-points-from-1-string)?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I am ignoring the sql aspect for now and am just focusing on the Regex portion hoping to use the demo provided

Comment: A regexp can only match a contiguous portion of the string. You can't get the many-to-one grouping you want with a regexp.

Comment: @Barmar, I'm no longer looking to get a many:one matching. Just trying to get the same output in my regexp as the demo link provided (https://regex101.com/r/RH5IUz/1). The op for the demo was able to get this as their output https://imgur.com/a/YWydFTy and I would like to do the same

Comment: Please put the desired result in the question, not the demo link.

Comment: Note that if you're planning on using this in MySQL, it doesn't use PCRE and doesn't have capture groups.

Comment: @Barmar, my desired result is in the question (under "desired one line expression") as well as the snapshot link on imgur, as is the demo link. Please ignore the prior requests for SQL help as I will tackle that problem when I get to it. Right now I wish to learn more about REGEX.

Comment: That seems to be a regular expression, not the result you want from using it. Please post the desired result as plain text, not an image link.

Comment: The image link has `[device name]:device_1`. I don't see that anywhere in the input.

Comment: All I'd like is the regular expression syntax so I dont get the error "Your regular expression does not match the subject string." I would just like to see what is different between the demo's regex and my modified regex using different non-capture groups.

Comment: "All I'd like is the regular expression syntax so I dont get the error" So it doesn't matter *what* it matches, as long as it doesn't get an error?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion: The demo has an example string and a regex which returns no errors and displays matches correctly on the side of the regex101 page (the snapshot). I am modifying the demo link with the updated non-capture and capture groups per the updated string provided in this post. I would like to 1-UNDERSTAND why just changing the non-capture groups returns the error and 2- actually see the match results as shown in the demo. It IS important that the match is correct and returns no error, but more so that I understand what I am missing so I can learn

Comment: @Barmar, yes I am aware that both individual regex work and return an output with no error. I am trying to consolidate them into one regex as shown in the demo

Comment: The most obvious problem is `\[` before `(?:current_version`. Removing that doesn't fix it, but there may be other similar issues.

Comment: You have an extra `:` in `(?::current_version`

Comment: @Barmar AMAZING that was it! so small. I got rid of the "\[" as well. Now I need to resolve the extra ' at the end of the version. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the regexp is the problem:

```
\[(?::current_version = ')
```

There's no `[` or `:` before `current_version` in the input. Removing them allows the regexp to match.

```
(?:device_model = \['?|data9 = \['|, ')([^'\],\r\n]*)(?=.*\r?\n(?:[ \t]*\[.*\r?\n)*?[ \t]*(?:current_version = ')(.*))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/9VmjVi/1)

Comment: thats perfect thank you. I updated the second capture group ending as well

````
(?:device_model = \['?|data9 = \['|, ')([^'\],\r\n]*)(?=.*\r?\n(?:[ \t]*\[.*\r?\n)*?[ \t]*(?:current_version = ')(.+)\')
````